# JS - Issue: Audit usage of navigator.userAgent, navigator.appVersion, and navigator.platform

Tags: javascript, html, console

I just started working on a new code few days ago an I only wrote a few lines But I see this error in the console with an issue:

[I USE BRAVE BROWSER] --- Screenshot -->
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTSwo.png)

HTML Code --> https://ibb.co/ydbK84N

JS Code --> https://ibb.co/cFhK8j4

I have no idea what the issue is and the textContent element is not even NULL.

I tried some change in code but nothing changed in the error...

I really would be appreciated if someone help me get rid of this.

Comment: can you show us your code?

Comment: Please [do not post a link to a painting of the code, or of error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1048572)! You can [edit] your question to include the code as [formatted text](/help/formatting).

Comment: @Bergi sorry i did not knew but i tried to post the code and even it was formatted it said i need to format it